# String [] to char Array using java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a weird situation, am working on a Data base project that only gives me a string [] s = ["A","B","C","D"] and I wanted to change from string array to Char Array since it's a char but i dunno what function to use to convert the entire array to char with one line of code.
char ch = [ 'A', 'B', 'C'] --> this is what am looking to get

My plan B  is to loop the entire string and convert to char one by one. but am avoiding that one.

any help I will highly appreciate

Comment: see String.toCharArray

Comment: that helps, thanks

Comment: he is asking from String [] i guess.

Comment: it's String [] S = [ "A", "B", "C"] this is the example .I wanted to get char ch = [ 'A', 'B', 'C']

Answer (score 1):

this might help you.

Would be better if we could use `Stream<char>`, but, this does not work, so, we need to use the wrapper class.

Since you want the first index, you can use 0.
String.charAt(index) returns a char primitive, so, it will use less memory than a String.substring(...) that returns a new String.

```
    final String[] array = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    final Character [] char_array = Arrays.stream(array)
            .map(s -> s.charAt(0))
            .toArray(Character[]::new);

    for(char a: char_array) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Comment: There is no request for primitive char.

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams, this will return a char [] array.

```
 Arrays.stream(S).map(s -> s.substring(0,1)).collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray();
```

Full code

```
String [] S = { "A", "B", "C"} ;

 

      char [] ch =Arrays.stream(S).map(s -> s.substring(0,1))
.collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray();


       for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++){
           System.out.println(ch[i]);
       }
```

For better use, I suggest making a method that implements this stream and returns a `char []`

```
public char [] convertToChar(String [] yourArray){

       return Arrays.stream(youArray).map(s -> s.substring(0,1)).collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray();
    }
```